# What statistical test should I used for this study design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, social-science

I am very much not statistics minded and could really do with some help figuring out what statistical test I should be using here:

My premise is:

Activity X can lead to outcome Y which in turn can lead to outcome Z.

I want to look at whether Activity X leads to outcome Y and also whether that then leads to outcome Z under three different conditions.

For example:
Dancing together can lead to social bonding and therefore money sharing.

I want to look at the extent to which whether dancing together leads to social bonding (scale 1-10 based on questionnaire) and also whether that leads to money sharing (Yes/No based on economic game) in three different conditions: dancing together in-person, dancing together over Zoom, and a mixture of the two.

I predict that in the in-person condition there will be high social bonding and high money sharing, in the hybrid condition there will be less social bonding and less money sharing, and in the Zoom condition there will be significantly less social bonding and no money sharing.

What statistical test would be appropriate here? Or should it be multiple that can be compared somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated! All the statistics will be done in R.

Comment: No statistical test can tell you if A causes B. They can tell you if there is an association, but not a causal link. It is the experimental design, particularly the control tests and measurements, that allow you to say anything about causality.

Answer (score 1):

not an expert, but you could use ANOVA to compare the means of the three groups (dancing live, dancing zoom, dancing hybrid) with regards to social bonding score. Then you can do the same with money sharing as an outcome variable of the three conditions. To include all three in a model you could do a mediation analysis (how does dancing condition impact money sharing by modulating social bonding.)

Comment: Thank you! I'm assuming some kind of linear model wouldn't work then? (e.g.  looking at the effect of the three conditions on social bonding and money sharing, and seeing which are more statistically significant). Sorry if that's a dumb question!

Comment: yes you can also do that, but dont look at which one is more significant only but which one showed the stronger correlation or effect size as a first priority and then look at the significance too.

Comment: but I would do both if I were you and then you can probably also do post hoc tests (simple t tests and correlations) between and within the three groups too.

Comment: Thank you so much!